# time complexity of nested maps cpp

Tags: c++, maps

suppose we have `map<int,map<int,int>>m` then
   what should be the time complexity of this `m[x][y]` ?

I think it should be `logn*logm` if number of `x` is `n` and number of `y` is `m`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I think it should be logn*logm if number of x is n and number of y is m.

No. You perform two map lookups on two separate maps. You don't have any repetition. One map being inside the other does not affect the complexity.

When you perform two operations in a sequence, the complexity is the sum of the complexities of the individual operations. Thus in this case the complexity is O(log N + log M) where N is the size of the one map, and M is the size of the other map - which can be simplified to O(log N) where N is the size of the larger map.

Answer (score 2):

`std::map`s `operator[]` has logarithmic complexity. It is not clear why you multiply the individual complexities. You look up one element in a map and then you look up a different element in a different map. Maybe it gets more obvious if you write it as

```
auto& a = m[x];
auto& b = a[y];   // same as auto& b = m[x][y];
```

Hence you have `log k` and `log n` (assuming `m` has `k` elements and `m[x]` has `n` elements), which adds to a total of `O( log n + log m)`.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have

```
std::map<int,std::map<int,int>> m{/*should be filled with something*/};
m[42][1337]; //We want complexity of this statement
const auto n1 = m.size(), n2 = m[42].size();
```

. The complexity of `operator[]` is in O(log(n)) where n is the size of the map. the statement calls the operator on the first map, and then on the second, so we have a time complexity of O(log(n1) + log(n2)). Lets define n as the maxiumum of n1 and n2  we get O(2*log(n)) which is also in **O(log(n))**

So you get a complexity in O(log(n)).

Also to clearify: The acutal values of X and Y i.e. the numbers you give the operator to lookup in the map are not n, and have nothing to do with the time complexity, in theory.

Comment: Good point with the simplification.